# 3rd Party Login in wordpress

Tags: posts, comments, user-access

I have two sites. One on wordpress and one non wordpress site. Now, I have used the header and footer from my non-wordpress site. What i want is that if user logs in on my non-wordpress site then he may use the same email and name to comment on my wordpress site.

I get the user info from the non-wordpress site of the user via a CURL request. The main problem I have is how to use user's email and name to post comment.

I tried using this:

```
global $current_user;
$current_user->user_email = $body->user->email;
$current_user->user_firstname = $body->user->name;
```

Here $body has the email and name of  user logged in from my non-wordpress site.

How can i do this?

Comment: Domain of the both sites are same or not? write the url for both site also.

Comment: Yeah..same domain

Comment: Then you can do it via ajax. Send an ajax request to wordpress site for loggin the user. :)

Comment: are they subdomains? you need to provide more information like, how the user info is stored, is it in cookie or session?

Comment: I have done that..I am not sure about how to use the info of the user

Comment: @MortalViews Yes they are subdomains. I have edited my question. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code which i use to login between two site one is in wordpress and one is non-wordpress. I send an ajax request to wordpress site having email and password as data. After get this data on wordpress site i user [`wp_signon`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function to login the user. Here is the code.

```
function sign_in_action() {
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $creds['remember'] = $_REQUEST['remember'];
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) ):
        echo false;
        exit();
    else:
        echo true;
        exit();
    endif;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sign_in_action', 'sign_in_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_sign_in_action', 'sign_in_action');
```

Once the login is successful if user come to the wordpress he is login automatically because wordpress save the cookie for the user.

The same code you have to write for logout also if user logout from non-wordpress site you have to logout it from wordpress site. For this you have to send an ajax request to wordpress site which use [`wp_logout`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout) function for logout the user.

```
function logout_action() {
    wp_logout();
    echo true;
    exit()
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_logout_action', 'logout_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_logout_action', 'logout_action');
```

This is working code that i use for my site. I don't know how you use database of user in wordpress and non-wordpress site. I use common `wp_users` table for both wordpress and non-wordpress site.